# Missing python modules in mic2 package

Tags: drivers, python

I am on Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS and I've installed mic2 package which is now complaining like this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "/usr/bin/mic-image-creator", line 35, in <module>
   import mic.appcreate as appcreate
ImportError: No module named appcreate
```

But a quick search reveals:

```
$ find /usr/ -name "*appcreate*"
/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/mic/appcreate
/usr/share/pyshared/mic/appcreate
```

Is it a package bug? Should I probably configure python (which I am new to) somehow to locate the module?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I was previously trying to install mic by hand from sources and that left some python files related to `mic` in `/usr/*`

Now that I've cleaned `/usr/*` from those, the package installs and mic runs.